# Menú de opciones

Tags: c, while, switch, menu

Para una tarea, tengo que escribir un programa que muestre continuamente el siguiente menú de opciones hasta que el usuario seleccione la opción 5 para salir:

1. Mostrar divisores (ejercicio 4)
2. Calcular el número e (ejercicio 5)
3. Contar palabras en una frase (ejercicio 6)
4. Calcular el coseno (ejercicio 7)
5. Salir

Cuando el usuario elige una opción entre 1 y 4, debe ejecutar el código correspondiente para realizar la acción indicada. Las acciones correspondientes a las opciones 1, 2, 3 y 4 del menú coinciden con los ejercicios 4, 5, 6 y 7 que ya he resuelto.

###### EJERCICIO 4:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x, i;
    printf("Introduzca un numero natural: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Los divisores de %d son: ", x);
    for(i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        if((x%i) == 0){
            printf("%d, ", i);
        }
    }
}
```

###### EJERCICIO 5:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int n,i;
float e=1.0, nFact=1;
printf("Introduzca el valor de n: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
for( i =1; i<= n ; i++)
{
    nFact*=i;
    e = e + (1.0/ nFact);
}
printf("Numero e = %f \n", e);
}
```

###### EJERCICIO 6

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    char c, old_c;
    int num = 1;

    printf("Introduzca una frase acabada en punto: \n");
    scanf("%c", &c);    
    do {
        old_c = c;
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if (c != ' ' && old_c == ' ') {
            num++;
        }
    } while (c != '.');

    printf("Numero de palabras = %d.\n", num);
}
```

###### EJERCICIO 7:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double x, elem, sum;
    int n, i, j;

    printf("Introduzca un valor real (x): ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("Introduzca un valor natural (n): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0, sum=0; i<=n; i++) {
        for(j=1, elem=1; j<=2*i; j++) {
            elem = elem * x/j;
        }
        if (i%2==0) {
            sum = sum + elem;
        } else {
            sum = sum - elem;
        }
    }
    printf("Cos(%.2lf) = %.2lf\n", x, sum);
}
```

Una vez finalizada la acción, el menú de opciones debe aparecer de nuevo en la pantalla. Cuando el usuario elige la opción 5, el programa termina. Si el usuario introduce cualquier otro valor que no sea 1, 2, 3, 4 y 5, aparecerá el mensaje "Opción equivocada" y se volverá a mostrar el menú de opciones.

Al intentarlo, utilicé un buco do while con switch_case:

```
#include "stdio.h"


int main() {
    char e;
    int a, b, c, d, x, n, i, j;
    
   do {
     printf("1. Mostrar divisores (ejercicio 4) \n");
     printf("2. Calcular numero e (ejercicio 5) \n");
     printf("3. Contar palabras de una frase (ejercicio 6) \n");
     printf("\nEscoja una opcion: ");
     scanf("\n%s", &e);
     switch (e){


            case '1':
            
                
                int main() {
                int x, i;
                printf("Introduzca un numero natural: ");
                scanf("%d", &x);
                printf("Los divisores de %d son: ", x);
                for(i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                if((x%i) == 0){
                printf("%d, ", i);
                      }
                     }
                }
                
                break;
            
              case '2':
            
                
                int main()
                {
                int n,i;
                float e=1.0, nFact=1;
                printf("Introduzca el valor de n: ");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                for( i =1; i<= n ; i++)
                {
                nFact*=i;
                e = e + (1.0/ nFact);
                }
                printf("Numero e = %f \n", e);
                }
                break;
            
             case '3':
            

                int main() {
                    char c, old_c;
                    int num = 1;

                printf("Introduzca una frase acabada en punto: \n");
                scanf("%c", &c);    
                do {
                     old_c = c;
                     scanf("%c", &c);
                     if (c != ' ' && old_c == ' ') {
                                           num++;
                               }
                 } while (c != '.');

               printf("Numero de palabras = %d.\n", num);
}
               break;

            case '4':
            
             

             int main() {
             double x, elem, sum;
             int n, i, j;

             printf("Introduzca un valor real (x): ");
             scanf("%lf", &x);
             printf("Introduzca un valor natural (n): ");
             scanf("%d", &n);
             for(i=0, sum=0; i<=n; i++) {
             for(j=1, elem=1; j<=2*i; j++) {
            elem = elem * x/j;
        }
        if (i%2==0) {
            sum = sum + elem;
        } else {
            sum = sum - elem;
        }
    }
    printf("Cos(%.2lf) = %.2lf\n", x, sum);
}
            break;
                      
            default:
                printf("Opcion incorrecta!\n");
        }
    } while (e != 5);
    printf("\nAdiós");
    ;

}
```

Necesito evitar la redundancia antes de corregir algo más, ¿debería declarar las variables en main en lugar de en case? ¿No sería eso conflictivo? ¿Cómo puede saber a cuál me refiero?

Comment: Lo que has compartido ni funciona ni compila. La función `main` sólo puede tener una definición, pero aunque pudiera tener más: en [tag:c] no puedes declarar funciones dentro de funciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, estás definiendo la función `main` en todas y cada una de las opciones. Esto es un error gravísimo y no está permitido en `C`. Los ejercicios que has resuelto mételos dentro de una función nueva y la llamas como tú quieras, y estas funciones serán llamadas dentro de las opciones del menú.

Por otro lado, intenta no declarar nombres de variables sin sentido como tienes `a`, `b`, `c`... Dales un significado real.

Otra cosa, en el `scanf` que haces para obtener la variable de control de tu menú estás haciendo `%s`, cuando tienes un `char` en vez de un `string`. Debes poner `%c`. Aunque te recomiendo trabajar con un `int`, ya que tus opciones de menú son números, de tal forma que debes obtener el valor mediante `%d`.

Un código que podría servirte sería algo parecido a esto:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void ejercicio4 ( void )
{
    int x, i;

    printf("Introduzca un numero natural: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Los divisores de %d son: ", x);

    for(i = 1; i <= x; i++) 
    {
        if((x%i) == 0)
        {
            printf("%d, ", i);
        }
    }
}

void ejercicio5 ( void )
{
    // Incluir código de tu ejercicio 5
}

void ejercicio6 ( void )
{
    // Incluir código de tu ejercicio 6
}

int main() {
    int opcion;

   do {
         printf("\n1. Mostrar divisores (ejercicio 4) \n");
         printf("2. Calcular numero e (ejercicio 5) \n");
         printf("3. Contar palabras de una frase (ejercicio 6) \n");
         printf("\nEscoja una opcion: ");
         scanf("%d", &opcion);
     
         switch (opcion)
         {
             case 1:
                ejercicio4();
                break;
            
            case 2:
                ejercicio5();
                break;
            
            case 3:
                ejercicio6();
                break;
            
            // OTRAS OPCIONES....
        
            case 5:
                break;
            
            default:
                printf("Opcion incorrecta.\n");
                break;
         }
    }while (opcion != 5);

    printf("FIN DE PROGRAMA");
    return 0;
}
```

Fíjate que al trabajar con funciones no necesitas declarar variables globales dentro del `main`, ya que lo que haces es ir a la función a trabajar, operar con las variables locales de la función, imprimir resultados y volver al menú principal.

Comment: No está llamando a la función `main` en todas y cada una de las funciones, está definiéndola, lo cuál no es posible en [tag:c].

Comment: Corregido. Gracias.